# snappy/snappymodule.cc(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'snappy-c.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm not able to install python-snappy module. I have successfully installed snappy module first but getting below error for python-snappy.

```
(new-env) C:\Automation\test-automation\connect>pip install python-snappy
Collecting python-snappy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/35/65d9f8cc537129894b4b32647d80212d1fa342877581c5b8a69872cea8be/python-snappy-0.5.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: python-snappy
  Running setup.py install for python-snappy ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Automation\test-automation\new-env\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\vagrant\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\
2\\pip-install-17b8xwg1\\python-snappy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))
" install --record C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-record-vdvhb6a5\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Automation\tes
t-automation\new-env\include\site\python3.7\python-snappy:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\snappy
    copying snappy\hadoop_snappy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\snappy
    copying snappy\snappy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\snappy
    copying snappy\snappy_cffi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\snappy
    copying snappy\snappy_cffi_builder.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\snappy
    copying snappy\snappy_formats.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\snappy
    copying snappy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\snappy
    copying snappy\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\snappy
    running build_ext
    building 'snappy._snappy' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\snappy
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Automation\test-automation\new-env\include "-IC:\Program Files (x8
6)\Python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\
10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
 Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /EHsc /Tpsnappy/snappymodule.cc /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\snappy/snappymodule.obj
    snappymodule.cc
    snappy/snappymodule.cc(31): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'snappy-c.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Automation\test-automation\new-env\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\vagrant\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-17b8xwg1\
\python-snappy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Us
ers\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-record-vdvhb6a5\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Automation\test-automation\new-env\inc
lude\site\python3.7\python-snappy" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\vagrant\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-17b8xwg1\python-snappy\

(new-env) C:\Automation\test-automation\connect>
```

Successfully installed snappy and Visual Studio 14.

Comment: Well, it looks like editing challenge.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use Visual studio? If not I suggest an open source alternative, `Spyder`

Answer (score 4):

In such cases you can download the wheel files compiled by C. Gohlke.

All you need to do is that find which dependencies you need and then search on the [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) according to your python version.

After downloading the file, go to that file location and simply install it using pip.

For example in this case lets say you are using python 3.7 version and you want to install python-snappy then first download `python_snappy‑0.5.4‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` and then save it on some location. Again go to that location and simply use `pip install python_snappy-0.5.4-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`.

That's it.